# In a brick layout for tile, how do I handle exposed cut edges?

Tags: bathroom, tile, bathtub, finishing

My second in the line of "redoing a bathroom" questions.  For our tub surround, my wife and I have picked out some very nice 16"x4" subway tiles, that we would like to arrange in a brick pattern.  To surround the tile, and finish exposed edges, we have ordered some 16x4 bullnose.  For example:

http://monty.princeton.edu/~mark/tile_layout.gif

However, in order to have a brick pattern, every other row will require a 16x4 tile to be cut in half, leaving an unfinished edge on the tile.  I have noticed that the tile we picked out has a very *slight* roundness to the edges of the tile.  Cutting the tile in half will cause a sharp corner where the cut tile butts up against the bullnose:

http://monty.princeton.edu/~mark/tile_layout_edge.gif

The top is a full 16x4 viewed from the edge (notice the rounded top edge where it butts against the bullnose) whereas the bottom is the cut tile (notice the sharp corner where it butts against the bullnose).  Now, in this image I have exaggerated the bevel on the top face of the tile, it is quite a bit more subtle than this.

How is this typically handled?  Is there a way to soften the sharp corner?  Or is it typically not noticed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience it's usually not noticed.

You'll be grouting as well and unless you're *very* precise with the grout there'll be some variation with grout depth and width which will "even out" the effect.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I was hoping that would be the case, and these tiles were not cheap, so I'd prefer to hear experience such as yours before cutting into them ;)